# Save and iterate array in php-mysql

Tags: php, html

I have the following code to save an array in my DB:

```
public function agregarBolsasModel($datos, $tabla) {
        $datosL=array($datos["valoresBox"]);
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(:one, :two, :three)");

        for($p = 0; $p < sizeof($datosL); $p++) {
            $stmt -> bindParam(":one", $datos["loteNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":two", $datos["cajaNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":three", $datosL[$p], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        $stmt->close();
}
```

The value of `three` is an array like `[1,2,3]` where I don't know the size cause it's a dynamic array, but I can't save the data in my DB, also when I tried to save the data I received the following error:

> Fatal error>: Uncaught error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::close()

what is my mistake? How could I do to fix that?

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PDO doesn't have a "close" function. You can do

$this->db = null;

In your case, on $stmt

Answer (score 2):

Use $stmt = null;
instead of $stmt->close();